# Equivalent PL/pgSQL Functions (Postgres) for T-SQL Functions (Sybase)

Tags: postgresql, t-sql, sybase, plpgsql

Within a migration from Sybase to PostgreSQL I have to translate some triggers. While doing this I got in some problems with functions that we use within Sybase (T-SQL) and I don't find equivalents in PostgreSQL (PL/pgSQL).

For example, we use the following statements in Sybase for which I have to find an equivalent:

1. `select @inscount = count(*) from inserted`
2. `select @delcount = count(*) from deleted`
3. `@@rowcount` (The number of modified rows)
4. rollback transaction

Answer (score 1):

1, 2 and 3 are not needed in Postgres if you use row-level triggers (something Sybase and Microsoft don't have).

As the trigger is called once for each row, those numbers are essentially always `1`.

Access to the modified or deleted data is possible through the record variables `OLD` and `NEW`.

More details are in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html

You cannot rollback or commit something inside a trigger (or a function) - which is a *very* scary thought anyway. So there is no equivalent to 4)